# Install ubuntu 64bit server to another server using ssh

Tags: server, ssh, 64-bit

- I need to change my `Ubuntu 32bit server` to `64bit`.
- I have two servers,both server in two location and need to install `Ubuntu 64bit` using `SSH`.
- I'm longing into Linux server and then longing to Ubuntu 34bit server I need to now install Ubuntu 64bit to second server (Ubuntu 32bit server).
- Is this is possible? If it is possible what are the step to do this?
- please I need a quick help ?

Comment: i hope there is no change to migrate(change) the architecture(i.e 32-bit to 64-bit) you need to replace with 64-bit server by installing it.

Comment: is there is way to do that migrate?

Comment: migration not possible, need to replace it. is your hardware support 64-bit os ?

Comment: yes,It is supported..

Comment: then you can replace it, can't migrate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really replace the system completely.

Only, if you absolutely have no choice and a gun to your head, you can check the following guide:
http://users.digitalkingdom.org/~rlpowell/hobbies/debian_arch_up/index.html

It's for debian but you need to be an expert anyway, so you should be able to apply it.